# Solution to a two dimensional transport PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've trying to solve this PDE with a initial condition using the method of characteristics
\begin{equation*}
u_t + yu_x - xu_y = 0 ,  \quad u(0,x,y)=e^{-(x-1)^2-(y-1)^2}
\end{equation*}
but i'm struggling since the possible results that i have gotten don't satisfy the PDE.

I have tried solving $x'= y$ and $y'= -x$ but i only get something as mentioned above.

So, any idea on how to aproach to this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of characteristics (below) leads to the solution :
$$u(x,y,t)=e^{-x^2-y^2+2(x+y)\cos(t)+2(x-y)\sin(t)-2}$$

[image]

Comment: could u please explain me why did u take $tan(c_2)$, i dont really understand why is that possible, thank you @JJacquelin

Comment: You can take any function that you want. $\Phi(X,Y)=F\left(g(X),h(Y)\right)$, any functions $\Phi,F,g,h$. A function of arbitrary function is an arbitrary function as well.